# Parsing time if milliseconds not available with Jackson annotations

Tags: jackson

Usually I get dates like 2017-02-25T06:36:21.530

And I use the following annotations:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty
```

However this fails if the time provided has no milliseconds e.g. 2017-02-25T06:36:21
Is there a way to specify to just ignore milliseconds in this case use 000 for instance?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use the custom deserializer, but for doing this kind of deserialization you don't need it, as well as the @JsonFormat. 
You can just configure the mapper and will work with the dates in that format (iso 8601), even without milliseconds:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    // In case you use Java 8 dates
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```